# how to give permission for the user to view private doc using scribed API

Tags: java, javascript

I am using scribd java script API to view a pdf file in my website.

I have  uploaded one pdf file and made the pdf document private.

I want it to be viewed via script in my code.

I cant call a private document without autentication - so it does not allow me to view.

So i need to give something like this

```
 scribd_doc.addParam("use_ssl", true);
 scribd_doc.grantAccess('username','sessionid','password');
```

I do not understand what is session id here .

how should i get it.. pls explain how to given authentication as above using username and password

pls refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session ID` is a string unique to the user's browser. This would ordinarily be the session ID you store in the user's cookie, or a derivative thereof. What's important is that if the same user logs in from a different computer, this ID must change.For more details:
http://www.scribd.com/publisher/ipaper_secure

Comment: yes - I got that code from that link only.. my need is that I want to give permission to view that doc from my product to all user who logs in my product - Do u get wat i want ?

Comment: try:scribd_doc.addParam('public', true);

Comment: You are not allowed to view this document.
Sorry, we can't display this document.....
i get this :(